# Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException - AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to build an app where if user click a button, it will shows an alertdialog with `multiChoiceItems`,

I assigned the value of the option in multiChoiceItems from an `ArrayList` (which has been converted to arrayed string), but when I tried to click the button, the program is error instead of showing the dialog with the options,

It throws a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` exception, but I don't know where is the error and how I should fixed it.

Here is my piece of code and Logcat :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_todolist);
    sessionAndDeclaration();
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    new AttemptGetReceiver().execute();
}

class AttemptGetReceiver extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(CreateToDoList.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.show();
        pd.setCancelable(true);
    }

    // will get group member from selected group id to be receiver
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int success = 0;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GroupId", groupId));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                    params);
            success = json.getInt("success");
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Success", "Getting parsed data");
                mMember = json.getJSONArray("members");

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mMember.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = mMember.getJSONObject(i);
                        String parsedMember = c.getString("Username");
                        mMemberList.add(parsedMember);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();

    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bChooseReceiver:
        alertDialogListReceiver();
        break;

}

public void alertDialogListReceiver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stringList.clear();
    final String[] listMember = new String[mMemberList.size()];
    final boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[mMemberList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mMemberList.size(); i++) {
        listMember[i] = mMemberList.get(i);
    }

    stringList.clear();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            CreateToDoList.this);

    builder.setTitle("Choose Your Receiver : ");

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            xmlListReceiver.setText("Post To : ");

            for (int i = 0; i < listMember.length; i++) {
                if (itemsChecked[i]) {
                    stringList.add(listMember[i]);
                    itemsChecked[i] = false;
                }

                Log.d("flag", "after for");

            }
            String string = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
                xmlListReceiver.setText("Send To : ");
                string = string + " " + stringList.get(i);

            }
            xmlListReceiver.setText(xmlListReceiver.getText().toString()
                    + string);
        }
    });
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(listMember, new boolean[] { false, false,
            false }, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                boolean isChecked) {
            itemsChecked[which] = isChecked;
        }
    });
    builder.show();
    Log.d("flag", "bottom of alert dialog");
}
}
```

Logcat :

```
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969): Process: com.thesis.teamizer, PID: 28969
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$1.getView(AlertController.java:894)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2712)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2285)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1371)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1595)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
02-01 22:23:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28969):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set default item state (checked or not) here:

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(listMember, new boolean[] { false, false,
        false }, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
```

for 3 items, but you can have a different number of item: `mMemberList.size()`, from the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[],%20boolean[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)):

> checkedItems   specifies which items are checked. It should be null in which case no items are checked. **If non null it must be exactly the same length as the array of items.**

Using `null` for `checkedItems` should fix the issue:

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(listMember, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
```

Comment: my bad, I should have paid attention to the package name.

Comment: Omg, How stupid I am.. of course it should adapt my arraylist size,  Thank you !!

Comment: IMHO, this case could be better handled (with a specific exception or something), as is it's a trap ;)

Comment: do you have any recommendation exception for something like this case? So i could prevent this in the future

Comment: No, I meant the Android API could probably handle this case in a better way